# Make an object uninstanciable except by using the function I set? Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am building a little library for fun and am wondering whether I have hit a design flaw or whether there is a common approach to my problem.

Lets say I have three objects

```
obj1 = function() {

    this.create2 = function() {
        return new obj2();
    }
}

obj2 = function() {

    this.create3 = function() {
        return new obj3();
    }
}

obj3 = function() {

    this.create4 = ......
}
```

I would like to stop people being able to instantiate `obj2` independently (`var obj2 = new obj2()`) and force them to use `obj1.create2` same for `obj2.create3` and so on?

Is there a proper solution to this problem?

Comment: Er, what? `obj1.create2` is `undefined` here as far as I can see. However, running `obj1()` will work... and pollute the global scope with `create2`.

Comment: You know what I mean `var obj1 = new obj1(); var obj2 = obj1.create2();` You are clever enough to read through the lines! Or are you not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one thing about your implementation that might be contradictory: the scope of your classes (that by the way you in my honest opinion called wrongly `obj`).

Given this snippet:

```
obj1 = function() {

    this.create2 = function() {
        return new obj2();
    }
}
```

There are 2 possibilities:

- Case 1: you keep the object `new obj2()` resulting from `this.create2()` within obj1 (private)
- Case 2: you give access to it from outside (public)

Corresponding solutions:

- For case 1: the scope of your class `obj2` is then wrong, and you should put the whole definition within `obj1`:

  ```
  obj1 = function() {
      obj2 = function() {
          this.create3 = function() {
              return new obj3();
          }
      }
      this.create2 = function() {
          return new obj2();
      }
  }
  ```
- For case 2: then the class `obj2` is indeed public and you have to leave it that way.

### Possible Workaround

What you may do is leave the objects their public status (public to their immediate outside scope, that is) but nonetheless encapsulate everything within a global object (the api mapper) which, itself, will expose only certain of its methods.

For example:

```
function api() {

    obj1 = function() {

        this.create2 = function() {
            return new obj2();
        }
    }

    obj2 = function() {

        this.create3 = function() {
            return new obj3();
        }
    }

    obj3 = function() {

        this.create4 = ......
    }

    this.object1 = new obj1;
    this.object2 = new obj2;
    this.object3 = new obj3;

}
```

and now, from anywhere else:

```
var o1 = api.object1.create2(); //OK: will instanciate a new obj2
var o2 = new obj2; //NOT OK: there's no access to obj2 from here
```

This is not OOP at all (accessing objects from a class you don't have access to is rather unseen), but as I said it's just a workaround.

I've seen in some frameworks the creator just making everything public, and prefixing "private" methods with "_", adding a comment like "This method/object is meant to be private please don't use outside". I think it's actually fair, thinking of how javascript is designed. Up to you to pick your way.

Comment: Thanks this has helped alot it does make sense to me now, my classes need to be public so I have to find another solution to my problem, thank you

Comment: See my next edit, I think I have a solution for your problem.